# SSDT - Only show records where Modified Date is more than 7 days

Tags: date, reporting, sql-server-data-tools

In my SSDT report I have a field coming from a database called modified date. I want in my table in my report to only display records where the modified date is more than 7 days old, so in another way if a record hasn't been modified in 7 days then show the record.

I've looked at the Filter properties of the table but can't figure out the exact way of achieving what I want

Does anyone have any suggestions/examples?

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to do this by adding a WHERE clause? "WHERE ModifiedDate < DATEADD(dd, -7, getdate())" should work. Not sure if I'm missing something in what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: @PeterSchott My data is coming from CRM Dynamics, basically I want to see what records have not been active, so by putting in a where clause where if the record hasn't been modified in 7 days then I want it to appear in my table in the report, i'll try what you suggested and get back to you

Comment: Worked great thank you, only change was instead of getdate() it was Today()